# MDX Hierarchy query

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, pentaho-cde

I work with Pentaho BI and I am preparing data for simple dashboard. I have records with two level date dimension (year and month). When I do query from saiku:

```
WITH SET [~ROWS] AS
Hierarchize({{[Date].[Year].Members}, {[Date].[Month].Members}})
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Count]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [data]
```

Pentaho create a sum for every first month, every second month... (1-12) and sum for each year. I need a sum for every `year+month` pair. How do I have to edit query?

Actual chart:

[image]

Target chart:

[image]

Comment: Did you try - `WITH SET [~ROWS] AS
Hierarchize({{[Date].[Year].[Year].Members}, {[Date].[Month].[Month].Members}})
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Count]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [data]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use Pentaho CDE to create a dashboard.

Set up `Banded Mode` property of MDX query to `Classic` (instead of `Compact`).

Comment: Tis is better but not ideal. I have from: !(http://postimg.org/image/8k3yinbw7/) this !(http://postimg.org/image/75k7ioqq3/) but i need this: !(http://postimg.org/image/6cwes1ml5) (from saiku). There are still sum of years.

Comment: Next step is to get rid of `All Datums ~ ` prefix (using JavaScript). Change the angle of date (using Extension points). It should look as you need after making those changes.. :)
  
Anyway, you should rather compare MDX outputs using CDA editor (open `CDA` file of your dashboard in Pentaho). You can see a raw data output in columns which is better to analyze. In chart you can't see all columns and rows of an MDX output.